# Reading comments into an array of dynamic size

Tags: c, arrays

So i have a series of comments in my markup file:

```
# comment1
# comment2
```

I want to read these into an array to be added to a comment array in my struct. **I do not know the amount of comment lines in advance**

I declare the comment array in my struct as follows:

```
char *comments; //comment array
```

Then I am starting to read the comments in but what i've got wasn't working:

```
int c;
//check for comments
c = getc(fd);
while(c == '#') {
    while(getc(fd) != '\n') ;
    c = getc(fd);
}
ungetc(c, fd);
//end comments?
```

Am I even close?

Thanks

Comment: No. 1. each single `getc` immediately consumes a character, so you loose half of them in your inner loop. 2. A single `char *comment` can only store a single C string (unless you want to separate them with other than 0 characters, of course). 3. You read characters but somewhere you forgot to store them.

Answer (score 1):

First

```
char *comments; //comment array
```

Is one comment not an array of comments.

You need to use realloc, to create an array of strings

```
char**comments = NULL;
int count = 10; // initial size
comments  = realloc(comments, count);
```

when you get > count

```
count*=2;
comments = realloc(comments, count);// classic doubling strategy
```

to put a string into the array (assuming comment is a char* with one comment in it

```
   comments[i] = strdup(comment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets()` form `<stdio>` to read one line at at time.

```
int num_comments = 0;
char comment_tmp[82];
char comment_arr[150][82];
while(comment_tmp[0] != '#' && !feof(file_pointer)){
    fgets(comment_tmp, 82, file_pointer);
    strcpy(comment_arr[num_comments], comment_tmp);
    num_comments++;
}
```

This has the limitation of only being able to store 150 comments.  This can be overcome by 1) setting a higher number there, 2) using dynamic memory allocation (think malloc/free), or 3) organizing your comments into a more flexible data structure like a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

When you see that line is comment store the value of comment in comment variable just go to next line and do this loop again. So the code :

```
char c = getc(fd);
while(c == '#') {
    while(getc(fd) != '\n') /* remove ; */ {
    *comment = getc(fd);
    ++comment;
    }
}
```

or use `fscanf` which is easier :

```
fscanf(fd,"#%s\n",comment); /* fd is the file */
```

Note that comment here is a **string** not an array of string.

For array of string it would be :

```
#define COMMENT_LEN 256

char comment [COMMENT_LEN ][100];
int i = 0;
while(!feof(fd) || i < 100) {
     fscanf(fd,"#%s\n",comment[i]);
     getch(); /* To just skip the new line char */
     ++i;
}
```